How to reply to emails from the proper email account?
I configured mbsync, msmtp, notmuch, notmuch.el message.el and org-msg.el to receive and send email with 4 different email account from Emacs notmuch MUA.
When I reply to an email the composer automatically has from: populated with user3 email, even if user1, user2 or user4 received the email.
How could I configure Emacs, so when I reply to an email received by user1, from: shows user1 email, when I reply to an email received by user2, from: shows user2 email, etc.?
Here is my config:
MUA
notmuch
notmuch
  (use-package notmuch
:load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/"
:custom
(notmuch-show-logo nil)
(notmuch-hello-auto-refresh t)
(notmuch-hello-recent-searches-max 5)
(notmuch-search-oldest-first nil)
(notmuch-draft-folder "Drafts")
;; Tags
(notmuch-show-all-tags-list t)
(notmuch-message-replied-tags '("+replied"))
(notmuch-message-forwarded-tags '("+forwarded"))
(notmuch-show-mark-read-tags '("-unread"))
(notmuch-draft-tags '("+draft"))
;; Searches
(notmuch-saved-searches
 `(
   (:name " unread" :query "tag:unread" :key "u")
   (:name " sent" :query "path:gmail-user1/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s/** path:gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s/** or path:gmail-user4/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s/** or path:free-user3/Sent/** or path:gmx-user1/Sent/**" :key "s")
   (:name "all mail" :query "*" :key "a")
))
;; Sent emails
(notmuch-always-prompt-for-sender t)
(notmuch-identities
 '(
   ("user1 <user1@gmx.com>")
   ("user3 <user3@free.fr>")
   ("user4 <user4@gmail.com>")
   ("user2 <user2@gmail.com>")
   ("user1 <user1@gmail.com>")
   ))
(notmuch-fcc-dirs
 '(
   ("user1@gmx.com" . "gmx-user1/Sent")
   ("user3@free.fr" . "free-user3/Sent")
   ("user4@gmail.com" . "gmail-user4/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s")
   ("user2@gmail.com" . "gmail-user2/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s")
   ("user1@gmail.com" . "gmail-user1/[Gmail]/Messages envoy&AOk-s")
   )
 )
;; Keybindings  
:bind
("C-x m" . notmuch-mua-new-mail)
(:map org-msg-edit-mode-map
      ("C-s" . notmuch-draft-save))
)

notmuch-transient
(use-package notmuch-transient
  :after (transient notmuch)
  )

Sending
org-msg
  (use-package org-msg
    :custom
    (mail-user-agent 'notmuch-user-agent)
    (org-msg-options "html-postamble:nil H:5 num:nil ^:{} toc:nil author:nil email:nil \\n:t")
    (org-msg-default-alternatives '((new      . (text html))
                    (reply-to-html    . (text html))
                    (reply-to-text    . (text)))
                  )
    (org-msg-convert-citation t)
    :config
    (org-msg-mode 1)
    )

message (MUA agnostic)
(use-package message
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (message-default-mail-headers "Cc: \nBcc: \n")
  (message-sendmail-envelope-from 'header)
  (message-kill-buffer-on-exit t)
  (sendmail-program "/usr/bin/msmtp")
  (send-mail-function 'sendmail-send-it)
  )


The other_email variable in ~/.notmuch-config has to be set with the other emails:
[user]
primary_email=user3@free.fr
other_email=user1@gmx.com;user4@gmail.com;user2@gmail.com;user1@gmail.com


